# React Hook Forms - Adding Dynamic Rows of Fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm using React Hook Form library. https://react-hook-form.com

If it's a simple form like Student Name, and Student Age, the application is quite simple.

```
const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
```

I just create those two input fields and register them.

```
               <div className="w-full flex flex-col mt-4">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter Name" {...register("name")}
                  />

                </div>
                <div className="w-full flex flex-col mt-4">
                  <label>Age</label>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Enter Age" {...register("age")}
                  />

                </div>
                <div>
                  <button onClick={handleSubmit(submitData)}>
                    Update
                  </button>
                </div>
```

The submitData function will get the `formData` which can be used. The `handleSubmit` binds the registered fields to `formData`

```
const submitData = async formData => {
  console.log(formData)
}
```

The `formData` will look as below:

```
{"name":"test", "age":"27"}
```

My requirement is to make this form dynamic, by allowing me to add many students. I should be able to repeat a set of these fields with a button called "Add Student". Every time I add a new student, it should create a new row of these two fields where I can add new students names. finally, the output of the `formData` should look like an array of students:

```
[{"name":"test1", "age":27},{"name":"test2", "age":28},{"name":"test3", "age":29} ]
```

I can create the UI to add the new fields, but I don't know how to bind them to the formData in react hook form. In the documentation, I couldn't find how to do this with react hook form.

Please help.

Comment: Can you please provide your full code, including usage of the useForm hook?

Comment: There isn't much other than what I've provided above. The useForm usage is:   const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm(); And from this register is used to register fields, which is shown above.

Comment: Here is a whole video on the process: https://youtu.be/61AlrA5BXzg, here is the sample from react-hook-form: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-ssugn

Answer (score 5):

I tried the following:

I created a state as follows:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([0,1,2])
```

I can update this when I add/remove items.

Now, for the fields, I wrapped them into a map as follows:

```
{items.map(i => (
    <div>
        <div className="w-full flex flex-col mt-4">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Name" {...register(`items[${i}].name`)}
            />

        </div>
        <div className="w-full flex flex-col mt-4">
            <label>Age</label>
            <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Age" {...register(`items[${i}].age`)}
            />

        </div>
    </div>
))}
```

This works.

Comment: Oh man, you just broke my heart, I was working on this for you. Lol

Comment: But how did you handle the dynamic keys for each form data value when `handleSubmit` is called?

Comment: Oh, you can still add your answer.

Comment: The form data now returns an array {"items": [{"name":"ss", "age","27"},{"name":"ff", "age","27"},{"name":"ff", "age","27"}]}}

Comment: Ok, well I just posted what I was doing, I wasn't done with it so it's not working as expected but hopefully, it should give you more ideas. @asanas

Comment: react-hook-form supports something like this called `useFieldArray` , which allows u to dynamically create/submit inputs

https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usefieldarray